# calling maps activity from fragment error support manager

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using tab layout with view pager and want to open the google maps in an activity by implementing a button in the fragment so that when user click a button that google maps activity will open up, but getting the following error in my logcat-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.finalhotelactivity.GoogleMapsApi.checkPermission(GoogleMapsApi.java:64)
        at com.example.finalhotelactivity.GoogleMapsApi.onCreate(GoogleMapsApi.java:53)
```

My Code for google maps Activity where i am getting the error

```
   public class GoogleMapsApi extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 23;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> arrayList=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    LatLng royalMirage = new LatLng(28.684356, 77.124681);
    LatLng cozyInn = new LatLng(28.742497, 77.146709);
    LatLng tisya = new LatLng(28.689439, 77.127331);
    LatLng cityHouse = new LatLng(28.695604, 77.111310);
    LatLng boktasVilla = new LatLng(32.233564, 77.195888);
    LatLng felicityInn = new LatLng(28.723161, 77.152231);
    LatLng cordialOrbit = new LatLng(28.724290, 77.146677);
    LatLng pleasantInn= new LatLng(28.730066, 77.161135);
    LatLng gangaView = new LatLng(30.102117, 78.292303);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayList.add(royalMirage);
        arrayList.add(cozyInn);
        arrayList.add(tisya);
        arrayList.add(cityHouse);
        arrayList.add(boktasVilla);
        arrayList.add(felicityInn);
        arrayList.add(cordialOrbit);
        arrayList.add(pleasantInn);
        arrayList.add(gangaView);

        checkPermission();
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        } else {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size();i++){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arrayList.get(i)).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arrayList.get(i)));
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }


    }
```

Fragment Code-

```
public class RoomFragment extends Fragment {

    Button map;


    public RoomFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_room, container, false);
        map = view.findViewById(R.id.openMap);

        map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),GoogleMapsApi.class));

            }
        });

        return view;



    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <ScrollView tools:context=".RoomFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:src="@drawable/felicity2">

    </ImageView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Map"
            android:id="@+id/openMap"
            android:layout_marginTop="600dp">

        </Button>
</FrameLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Comment: N0 as i am implementing map in an activity  and calling it through a fragment so i can't use getChildFragmentManager() in an activity @LalitFauzdar

Comment: Ok, But you just can't access it directly as you access it in an `Activity`. You've to create an `Object` of the `Activity` to get an instance of it and then through it, you can access it. Or, easy way, create a function in your `Activity` to initialize and open up the `MapsActivity` and access this function using the Activity's object in your `Fragment` as `((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();`.

Comment: Can i provide you the whold code so that you can see and tell me what's going on? If yes, provide me your mail please

Comment: You can add your Activity and Fragment's code here. You can also share the Activity's layout.

Comment: Done that@LalitFauzdar